# Ring structure of a localization

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring and let $A$ be an $R$-algebra which is moreover a finitely generated $R$-module. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. How is the ring structure of the localization $A_P$ defined?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's defined like in the field of fractions. Do you know how that is done?

Comment: $\frac{a}{s}\frac{b}{t}=\frac{ab}{st}$

Comment: ok, thank you for your comments.